# Test python class with method calls in __init__

Tags: python, unit-testing, class

I have a class which calls a lot of its methods in `__init__`. Since a lot is going on in these methods, I want to test them. Testing classes and class methods requires to instantiate the class and then call its methods. But if I instantiate the class, the methods will already be called before I can test it.

I have some ideas for possible solutions, but I am unsure if they are possible or a good way to go:

1. I could introduce a kwarg into the class like `init=True` and testing for it within `__init__`. So I could have default option to do all the magic stuff on object creation, and could deactivate it to instantiate the class and call functions separately.
2. I could define the methods outside the class in other classes or functions, if that works, and test them separately. The test of the bigger class would become something like an integration test.

Comment: you can make the `__init__` just do some basic stuff and have a `initialize()` method that calls other initialization methods. This way you can instantiate the class and test it without fully initializing it. For example, if your class opens a serial port, maybe you don't want that to be done when you instantiate the class, so having an initialize method that you can call afterwards might be handy. When using a class normally you will need to first instantitate it and then call `initialize()`.

Comment: If the class is already designed in the way it makes the most sense, then shouldn't you just be testing the result of the instantiation? That there are a lot of internal methods is mostly an implementation detail you shouldn't be testing…? If the state of the object is as expected after instantiation, the internal methods don't matter and don't need testing…? Otherwise, you may be hinting at the fact that the class is too convoluted and doing too much and should perhaps be refactored to be easier and more testable.

Comment: That would be a possibility too. But it appears a bit unhandy as later on the usage of the class would always require the call of initialize().

Comment: @deceze that might be true. I am a bit noobish self learning coder. This init is loading various data via pandas read_csv and numerical operations like interpolation etc. I already excluded some xmlparsers I wrote to another class. Maybe I should do the same with other methods.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you would like to test

If you want to check if all the calls are happening correctly you could mock underlying functionality inside the `__init__` method.

And then do assert on the mocks. (Pytest has a [spy](https://pytest-mock.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#spy) mocks which does not modify original behavior but could be tested as mocks for call count, arguments etc... I'm sure you could replicate that with unittest mock as well)

So you could mock everything that is necessary by the beginning and then create an instance.

If you want to check how it was assembled you could do this after initialization.

Generally modifying your source code just for the purpose of the test case is not a good idea.

Run your code through a debugger, check what you are looking for as a tester and automate it.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will have a look at that functionality.